# Написания функции генерации строки

Tags: php, функции

Здравствуйте, написал такую функцию генерации строки:

```
function gener($length = 1) {
$gener = '123456789QqWwEeRrTtYyUuIiOoPp[[]]aAsSdDFfGgHhJjKkLl:;ZzXxCcVvBbNnMm';
$gener =substr(str_shuffle($gener),1,$length)   
return $gener;
}
```

Два вопроса:

1. Видел много кода, где случайную строку получают используя циклы. Может то, что написано мной использовать нецелесообразно?
2. В 3 строке у меня `substr(str_shuflle())` стоит ли так писать функции? Или сперва сделать так `$gener = str_shuflle()` а потом в `substr` передавать переменную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых ошибка здесь:

```
substr(str_shuffle($gener), 1,$length);
```

Тут должнен быть `0`, а не единица:

```
substr(str_shuffle($gener), 0,$length);
```

Иначе, запросив у ф-ции рандомную строку длиной 67 символов, вы с удивлением обнаружите, что вернется строка длиной 66 символов, хотя даже строка `$gener` состоит из 67.

По-моему,

```
while (strlen($result) < $need_length)
    $result .= $gener[rand(0, strlen($gener) - 1)];
```

выглядит убедительнее. Кроме того, этот вариант может выдать гораздо больше уникальных результатов. К примеру, ваш вариант не сможет выдать строку "99", а код приведенный мной — сможет.

Еще есть прямо-таки суровая ошибка: что если понадобится рандомная строка длиной 67+ символов?

Я бы, по крайней мере, изменил код как-то вот так:

```
function gener($length = 1) {
    $gener = '123456789QqWwEeRrTtYyUuIiOoPp[[]]aAsSdDFfGgHhJjKkLl:;ZzXxCcVvBbNnMm';
    $length_need = min($length, strlen($gener));

    $result = '';
    while (strlen($result) < $length)
        $result .= substr(str_shuffle($gener), 0, $length_need);  // *

    return $result;
}
```

**Можно и более деликатно написать, чтобы избавиться от ситуации, когда перемешанную строку можно и не обрезать, а брать целиком.*

PS А зачем в строке допустимых символов две пары скобок `[]` — для повышения вероятности?

Comment: А может человеку нужно с уникальными символами? но при этом квадратных скобок может быть две.
Согласен разве что только с тем, что следует писать ноль, нежели 1.

Comment: Возможно, конечно, но я осмелился предположить, что в уникальности символов нужды нет и это просто упущение.

Comment: да это упущение,спасибо вам

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае, чем больше используете встроенные функции, тем быстрее и лучше получается код. Поэтому, если есть возможность написать через одну встроенную функцию, то обычно следует ее предпочитать. Но нужно быть аккуратным, иногда код может выглядеть коротко, но ресурсов есть целую кучку.

2) можно разделять на отдельные переменные, а можно писать одной строкой. Нужно смотреть как будет красивее и понятнее выглядеть. А для компилятора/интерпретатора в общем то побоку. Более того, даже код будет один и тот же. Но одно серьезное замечание есть - Вы используете переменную `$gener` дважды для разных целей. Поэтому, либо нужно ещё одну переменную, либо написать что то в виде

```
function gener($length = 1) {
    $gener = '123456789QqWwEeRrTtYyUuIiOoPp[[]]aAsSdDFfGgHhJjKkLl:;ZzXxCcVvBbNnMm';
    return substr(str_shuffle($gener),1,$length);
}
```

Comment: и вам тоже спасибо:)